# Possible to Restart SSH without Using SSH?

Tags: ssh

So I've managed to cut off the branch I was standing on so to speak. I was connected to a server and I ran sudo pkill  where the PID was a process I thought I wanted to kill and and I think I killed the ssh process that was listening on port 22.

Here is what happens when I try to connect now:

```
<computer>:~ <user>$ ssh -p 22 -v <user>@<ipaddress>
OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 47: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 51: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to <ipaddress> [<ipaddress>] port 22.
debug1: connect to address <ipaddress> port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host <ipaddress> port 22: Connection refused
```

Is there anyway I can connect via SSH? Or am I out of luck until I can login to the machine itself and restart the SSH server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try first a `curl -v telnet:<user>@<ipaddress>:22`

If it does not display a "Connected" message... there is no listener on port 22, which means the SSH daemon has been terminated.

You would then indeed wait for the opportunity to log on again, and restoart the SSH daemon.